# Thymeleaf conditional add tags

Tags: servlets, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I've a list of items in my request attribute("items"), the list will render by bootstrap 4 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/card/#card-decks) card deck 3 items per row. I can do it by using JSTL like

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${status.index%3 == 0}"> <!--Start new row-->
        <c:if test="${status.index > 0}"> <!--Close the previous deck-->
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <div class="card-deck mt-3"> <!--Create new deck-->
     </c:if>
     <div class="card bg-light">
         <h5 class="card-header">${item.id}</h5>
         <div class="card-body"></div>
     </div>  
</c:forEach>
```

Now, How do I achieve the same using Thymeleaf ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code would translate to Thymeleaf to something like the following code.

```
<th:block th:each="item, stat: ${items}">
    <th:block th:if="${stat.index eq 0}">
        <th:block th:if="${stat.index &gt; 0}">
            </div>
        </th:block>
        <div class="card-deck mt-3"> <!--Create new deck-->
    </th:block>
    <div class="card bg-light">
         <h5 class="card-header" th:text="${item.id}"></h5>
         <div class="card-body"></div>
     </div>  
</th:block>
```

Comment: The solution doesn't work. I got Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "item.id". It seems that the looping block ended before reaching the actual card div

Comment: Actually, this error occurs when Thymeleaf can’t find the field id on the object item. You need yo make sure the field’s name is exactly like you would find it in the model.